# Load Editable JQgrid with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I'm loading the JQgrid from the external Ajax call. I'm expecting my JQgrid to set the values with the edit fields once i pass my Array object.

I have tried all the ways which i found in google, but no luck.

Can someone point me where i'm making mistake ?

```
  var grid = $("#JobGrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['Product Name', 'Product ID', 'ProdTypeAvail', 'Piece/Sheet', 'Type', 'Pages', 'Copies', 'ExtraCharges', '', ''],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'strProductName', index: 'strProductName', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                    { name: 'strProductID', index: 'strProductID', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
                    { name: 'strProdTypeAvail', index: 'strProdTypeAvail', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
                    { name: 'iPiecesPerSheet', index: 'ipieces', editable: true, edittype: 'text', formatter: TrimZero },
                    { name: 'strProductType', index: 'strProducttype', editable: true, edittype: 'select' },
                    { name: 'iPages', index: 'iPages', editable: true, edittype: 'text', formatter: TrimZero },
                    { name: 'iCopies', index: 'iCopies', editable: true, edittype: 'text', formatter: TrimZero },
                    { name: 'dExtraCharge', index: 'dExtraCharge', editable: true, edittype: 'text', formatter: TrimZero },
                    {
                        name: 'Delete', label: 'Delete', title: 'Delete', width: 25, index: 'Delete', sortable: false,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return "<input type='button' value='del' />"
                            //return "<div><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/16/Button-Delete-icon.png'/></div>"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Duplicate', width: 25, index: 'Duplicate', sortable: false,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return "<input type='button' value='dup' />"
                            //return "<div><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/16/File-New-icon.png'/></div>"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                hidegrid: false,
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: true,
                height: '100%',
                scrollOffset: 0,
                rowNum: -1,
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false},
                rownumbers: true,
                caption: "Job Details",
                cellEdit: true,
                cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                pager: '#JobGridpager',
                localReader: { id: 'iRowID' },
```

....

My AJAX Call to load JQgrid

```
$j("#txtJobID").change(function () {
....
$j.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "http:/localhost:20/api/Job/GetFullJobDetails?Ary=" + JSON.stringify(obj),
dataType: 'json',
success: function (oJobdata) {
var oData = oJobdata.lstJobChildInfo;

grid.jqGrid('clearGridData');
grid.setGridParam({ data: oData });
grid[0].refreshIndex();
grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
...
```

My "oData" which I'm passing to my JQgrid...

[object1, object2]

Object1 :
dExtraCharge: 10
dJobDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
iAddCopy: 0
iCopies: 4
iFirstCopy: 0
iPages: 1
iPiecesPerSheet: 0
iRowID: 1
iTotalCopy: 0
lstJobChildInfo: null
strAction: null
strCompanyID: "C01"
strCustomerID: null
strCustomerName: null
strJobID: null
strJobchdid: null
strMobile: null
strProdTypeAvail: "PT01-PT02-PT03"
strProductID: "P005"
strProductName: "Art 130 +3"
strProductType: "One Side"
strProductTypeID: "PT01"
strStatus: null
strUserName: null
**proto**: Object

Object2 :
dExtraCharge: 0
dJobDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
iAddCopy: 0
iCopies: 4
iFirstCopy: 0
iPages: 2
iPiecesPerSheet: 2
iRowID: 2
iTotalCopy: 0
lstJobChildInfo: null
strAction: null
strCompanyID: "C01"
strCustomerID: null
strCustomerName: null
strJobID: null
strJobchdid: null
strMobile: null
strProdTypeAvail: "PT01-PT02-PT03"
strProductID: "P023"
strProductName: "Synthetic 125 Micron"
strProductType: "Diff Front And Back"
strProductTypeID: "PT02"
strStatus: null
strUserName: null
**proto**: Object

I have try setting,

- iRowID as ID
- jsonReader: { repeatitems: false},
- grid[0].refreshIndex();

but still grid remains empty without any data :-(

Comment: object 1 and 2 doesnt look to be valid json data.. also, put the `url: "http:/localhost:20/api/Job/GetFullJobDetails?Ary=" + JSON.stringify(obj),` directly into your jqgrid as a parameter.. you dont need seperate ajax call for it.

Comment: I have used add row data to fill my grid